# Can I create a new case when an email is sent to a closed case?

Tags: apex, trigger

We are implementing email to case and would like to create a new case whenever an email is sent to a closed case.  Our customers have been known to respond to old email strings to open up a new case.  We do not want to miss any emails that may get sent to an old email string.  My understanding is that there is no way to do this other than a trigger on the email object.  Can anyone direct me to a trigger that I could modify to accomplish this.  I am very new to Apex and coding and could use a little guidance.

Comment: did you finally solve it? I have the same problem